# Listing the contents of two different arrays - e.g. a deck of cards with "rank" of "suit"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a standard deck of cards in javaScript. I'm using two arrays - one for the ranks, the other for the suits. I'd like to run a simple program that will take the contents of these arrays and list them - so I'd get "Ace of Clubs, Two of Clubs, Three of Clubs..." etc

So far all I get is either a list of ranks eg "Ace, Two, Three..." followed by a list of suits "Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts...."

Here's my code

```
var output = document.getElementById("card");
var x = ["King ", "Queen ", "Jack ", "10 ", "9 ", "8 ", "7 ", "6 ", "5 ", "4 ", "3 ", "2 ","Ace "];
var y = ["Clubs ", "Diamonds ", "Hearts ", "Spades "];

//cycle through card ranks
for (i=0; i < x.length; i++){
output.innerHTML += x[i];
}

//cycle through card suits
for (j=0; j < y.length; j++) {
output.innerHTML += x[i]
}

function suitedList(){
  for (j=0; j < y.length; j++){
    for (i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    return x[i] + "of " + y[j] 
    }
  }
}
output.innerHTML = suitedList()
```

Can anyone help me with where I'm going wrong?

Comment: you're using `return` instead of string concatenation in `suitedList`

Comment: and you returning after the first iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate your strings before returning them from the function.  Something along the lines of:

```js
var output = document.getElementById("card");
var x = ["King ", "Queen ", "Jack ", "10 ", "9 ", "8 ", "7 ", "6 ", "5 ", "4 ", "3 ", "2 ", "Ace "];
var y = ["Clubs ", "Diamonds ", "Hearts ", "Spades "];

//cycle through card ranks
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  output.innerHTML += x[i];
}

output.innerHTML += '<br/>';

//cycle through card suits
for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
  output.innerHTML += x[i];
}

function suitedList() {
  // will hold all the concatenated values
  var outString = '';

  for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
    //console.log(outString);

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      // append suit/card to variable
      outString += x[i] + 'of ' + y[j];
      // adding a new line for easier reading (remove if unwanted)
      outString += '<br/>';
    }
  }
  
  // return concatenated string with all values
  return outString;
}

// override existing content of 'output'
output.innerHTML = suitedList();
```

```html
<div id="card"></div>
```

Comment: @Timothyp glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

You probably want your `suitedList` to look like this:

```js
output = document.getElementById("card");
var x = ["King ", "Queen ", "Jack ", "10 ", "9 ", "8 ", "7 ", "6 ", "5 ", "4 ", "3 ", "2 ","Ace "];
var y = ["Clubs ", "Diamonds ", "Hearts ", "Spades "];

function suitedList(){
  var list = "";
  for (j=0; j < y.length; j++){
    for (i=0; i < x.length; i++){
      list += x[i] + "of " + y[j] + "<br />";
    }
  }
  return list;
}

output.innerHTML = suitedList()
```

```html
<div id="card"></div>
```

of course, accumulation can be done in dozens of other ways, but the point is - you're returning from `suitedList` in the first iteration (`King of Clubs`) and overriding whole `innerHTML` with this value.

You have `output.innerHTML = suitedList()`, instead of `output.innerHTML += suitedList()`, which would append the list to current value of the block - that's OK if you want to list only the cards, but not OK if you also want the earlier lists to appear.